# How can I fix app crashes when calling id in Fragment?

Tags: android

I don't know why app crashes when reaching for id of others element. Do I need to add something more or give my phone permission?

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                        @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View searchProduct = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_category, container, false);
    Spinner productCategory = searchProduct.findViewById(R.id.spnCategory);
    category = productCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();

    productName = searchProduct.findViewById(R.id.edtSearch).toString();
    //getAPIDataProduct(category, productName);


    return searchProduct;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: your problem can be more clear if you share your crash report

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any items in Spinner, then the line `category = productCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();` will crash for NullPointerException, because `getSelectedItem()` will return null as it says in the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem()). You need to add items in the Spinner first!